# Merge array and regroup data by date

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I have two multidimensional array and want to group the data by date when it is possible (in php). I tried with merge and merge_recursive but it doesn't work.

1st Array :

```
array(100) {
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["2020-04-18"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["best_price_product"]=>
      float(489.1)
    }
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["2020-04-19"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["best_price_product"]=>
      float(489.1)
    }
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    ["2020-04-20"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["best_price_product"]=>
      float(489.1)
    }
  }
  [4]=>
  array(1) {
    ["2020-04-21"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["best_price_product"]=>
      float(489.1)
    }
  }
  ….
  }
```

2nd Array :

```
  array(88) {
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["2020-04-18"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["best_price_product_mp"]=>
      float(526.3)
    }
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["2020-04-19"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["best_price_product_mp"]=>
      float(526.3)
    }
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    ["2020-04-20"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["best_price_product_mp"]=>
      float(526.3)
    }
  }
  [4]=>
  array(1) {
    ["2020-05-03"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["best_price_product_mp"]=>
      float(526.3)
    }
  }
...
}
```

I would like the result to be like this :

```
  array(100) {
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["2020-04-18"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["best_price_product"]=>
      float(489.1)
      ["best_price_product_mp"]=>
      float(526.3)
    }
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["2020-04-19"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["best_price_product"]=>
      float(489.1)
      ["best_price_product_mp"]=>
      float(526.3)
    }
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["2020-04-20"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["best_price_product"]=>
      float(489.1)
      ["best_price_product_mp"]=>
      float(526.3)
    }
  }
  [4]=>
  array(1) {
    ["2020-04-21"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["best_price_product"]=>
      float(489.1)
      ["best_price_product_mp"]=>
      float(526.3)
    }
  }
[5]=> 
  array(1) {
    ["2020-05-03"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["best_price_product_mp"]=>
      float(526.3)
    }
  }
  ….
  }
```

In the merge of the two arrays, there are in addition to the merged dates, other dates which are unique in each array.

Thank you

Comment: Did you give up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can flatten both arrays and merge them:

```
$result = array_merge_recursive(call_user_func_array('array_merge', $a1),
                                call_user_func_array('array_merge', $a2));
```

The result will also be flattened, something like:

```
Array
(
    [2020-04-18] => Array
        (
            [best_price_product] => 1
            [best_price_product_mp] => 2
        ),
    [2020-04-19] => Array
        (
            [best_price_product] => 3
            [best_price_product_mp] => 4
        )
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help :-)